# Using spaces in bash scripts

Tags: bash

I have a script foo.sh

```
 CMD='export FOO="BAR"'
 $CMD
 echo $FOO
```

It works as expected

```
 >./foo.sh 
 "BAR"
```

Now I want to change FOO variable to `BAR BAR`. So I get script

```
 CMD='export FOO="BAR BAR"'
 $CMD
 echo $FOO
```

When I run it I expect to get `"BAR BAR"`, but I get

```
 ./foo.sh: line 2: export: `BAR"': not a valid identifier
 "BAR
```

How I can deal with that?

Comment: My bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.1.0(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin13.2.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do that.

And read [Bash FAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

> 1. I'm trying to save a command so I can run it later without having to repeat it each time
>
> If you want to put a command in a container for later use, use a
>   function. Variables hold data, functions hold code.
>
> ```
> pingMe() {
>     ping -q -c1 "$HOSTNAME"
> }
>
> [...]
> if pingMe; then ..
> ```

Comment: Interesting link but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LucM sure, because it solves the root of his problem.

Comment: Rarely do I see "${CMD[@]}" solutions. Actually I only find myself showing it most of the time. Can't wait to see the time when these posing "Bash FAQ"'s would again absorb it.

Comment: Added exact quote from bash faq that helped me.

Comment: @StasKurilin It's correct to answer your own question too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a variable as a command by just calling it (like in your `$CMD`).  Instead, use `eval` to evaluate a command stored in a variable.  Only by doing this, a true evaluation step with all the shell logic is performed:

```
eval "$CMD"
```

(And use double quotes to pass the command to `eval`.)

Comment: Just as a comment:  You might be interested in using _arrays_ to store your commands instead of plain string variables.  This way you easily can combine the command words and do not have to mind quoting the stuff.

Comment: @chepner, this greatly depends on your needs.  Since OP did not specify the concrete usecase, I rather tend to accept that what he says is true.  A typical "better" way to achieve the goal of using a short thing for a long command is a shell function, of course.  But maybe OP is going to store the read the command from a DB, so only a string is possible.  In this case using `eval` is the best solution.

Comment: An option is to retrieve the command and the arguments separately. Executing arbitrary code from an external source is the classic example of when *not* to use `eval`.

Comment: Maybe the source isn't _that_ external and maybe the code therefore isn't _that_ arbitrary.  Could be the comands are just read from a private DB which only OP can write.  It all depends and while I can imagine valid uses of `eval` you certainly are right to warn about the security issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do that is to use an array instead:

```
CMD=(export FOO="BAR BAR")
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Comment: If you can replace the plain string of the OP by an array, you should consider to go the whole nine yards and replace it by a shell function ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Obviously that's not always practical to situations especially when you're creating a command out of local function arguments.